# How to resize a window independently of the window is it locked to?

Tags: gnome, window-management

I am fairly new to using Ubuntu and have found if I snap a window to the left of the screen (either by dragging it to the edge of the screen or pressing <kbd>Super</kbd>+<kbd>Left</kbd>), and snap another window to the right of the screen they will 'lock' together. So if I resize the left window, the right window will also resize accordingly to ensure 100% of the screen space is used and there is no overlap of either windows. But this is a problem for me as I would like the windows to overlap slightly and use 60% of the screen width each.

Is there a way I can prevent this, and resize a window independently of the window it is locked to?

(In Windows if I press <kbd>Alt</kbd> while resizing it allows a window to be resized independently of the window it is locked to)

I am using Ubuntu 20.04 & GNOME 3.36.3.

Comment: Did you ever find an answer? I have the same question.

Comment: @ack_inc no I never did, apologies

Comment: The workaround I'm going with is: 1. Minimize one of the windows -> 2. Resize the other window to desired width -> 3. Maximize the first window. With this, the windows are no longer "snapped together"

Comment: This "feature" is extremely  annoying